# How to install OBS studio on Arch Linux without flatpak?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, software-installation, linux-headers, obs-studio

I am trying to install OBS studio using the standard Arch Linux repository instead of Flatpak.

First I visited the [Github page](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/wiki/install-instructions#unofficial-builds) to find dependencies.

> xserver-xorg version 1.18.4 or newer is recommended to avoid potential performance issues with certain features in OBS, such as the fullscreen projector.

```
$ sudo pacman -S xorg-server
```

> OpenGL 3.3 (or later) support is required to use OBS Studio on Linux. You can check what version of OpenGL is supported by your system by typing `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"` on Terminal.

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.1.7-arch1.1
```

> For virtual camera support, you need the v4l2loopback kernel module installed. You can install it with the following command:

> Arch Linux-based/Manjaro:

> You will need to install the kernel headers package of your actual kernel beforehand or the module will not be completely installed.

> `sudo pacman -S v4l2loopback-dkms`

> OBS Studio will normally load the module while starting the virtual camera if the module was not already loaded.

```
$ sudo pacman -S obs-studio
(2/2) Install DKMS modules
==> ERROR: Missing usr kernel headers for module v4l2loopback/0.12.7.
==> ERROR: Missing prod kernel headers for module v4l2loopback/0.12.7.
==> ERROR: Missing lib kernel headers for module v4l2loopback/0.12.7.
==> ERROR: Missing home kernel headers for module v4l2loopback/0.12.7.
...
```

After checking all three I tried running OBS studio.

```
$ obs
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vkkhrdisplay, vnc, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

It didn't run even though I uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times. What am I missing? Also how do install kernel headers package to enable virtual camera support on prerequisite 3?

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo pacman -S obs-studio`. This will install dependencies for you. Run `pacman -Si obs-studio` to see which optional dependencies you can install for extra functionality.

Now about your specific issue:

```
$ obs
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
```

Clearly, this is a Wayland issue. You could google this error message or search for "Wayland" on the [OBS page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Open_Broadcaster_Software) in the ArchWiki, where you will find a link to a section, which tells you to install `qt6-wayland` (OBS uses QT6 as of 2023) and set the `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` environment variable.